# Twitter API Search Get Tweet created_at Time

Tags: php, api, twitter

Hi I am currently using the twitter API and I am having trouble getting the created_at date for the tweet. The date which is being returned seems like the date when I requested the API, not the date the tweet was made.

I am able to get this date but if its the date I called the API it has no use to me. The API returned 100 tweets and every single created_at date was the exact same?

This is the code I have written:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
$tweets = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => "#TRIG", "result_type" => "recent", "count" => 100]);
print_r($tweets);
```

I am using this line of code to get the created_at date:

```
$tweetCreatedTime = $tweets->statuses[0]->created_at;
```

This is all the code I am using to count the tweets:

```
$timeHourAgo = time() - 3600;
$count = 0;
$tweetCoinCount = [];

for ($i=0; $i < round((count($coinSymbol) * 0.06)); $i++) { 
$tweets = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => "#" + $coinSymbol[$i], "result_type" => "recent", "count" => 100]);
$tweetsCount = count($tweets->statuses);
for ($t=0; $t < $tweetsCount; $t++) { 
    $tweetCreatedTime = $tweets->statuses[$t]->created_at;
    $tweetCreatedTimestamp = strtotime($tweetCreatedTime);
    if ($tweetCreatedTimestamp > $timeHourAgo) {
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
$tweetCoinCount[$coinSymbol[$i]] = $count;
$count = 0;
}
```

$coinSymbol is just a string of different currencies which I pull in using another API

all the tweets that are returned have the same created_at date.

Comment: I've just tried it and its returning diff dates, only the first is `Wed Oct 04 11:24:19 +0000 2017`, can you show how your looping through the tweets.

Comment: you are only getting date of first tweet with `$tweetCreatedTime = $tweets->statuses[0]->created_at;`  you need to loop through all tweets to get date for each tweet.

Comment: I have edited my question to show you to loop I used

Comment: If there is a better way of counting the tweets I would love to hear it as well because the way I am doing it is really slow

Comment: @LukeRayner added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rewrite your code, you have errors like `"#"+$coinSymbol[$i]` in it. `.` is string concatenation in PHP.

Ok, so if you have an array of symbols, you can then loop over them using a foreach and then grab your tweet count. Be aware that if you got 100s of currency symbols you're quickly hit twitters API limit.

```
$timeHourAgo = time() - 3600;
$tweetCoinCount = [];
$coinSymbol = [
    'TRIG',
    'BTC',
    'ETH'
];

foreach ($coinSymbol as $symbol) {
    $tweets = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => '#'.$symbol, "result_type" => "recent", "count" => 100]);

    $tweetCoinCount[$symbol] = 0;
    foreach ($tweets->statuses as $tweet) {
        if (strtotime($tweet->created_at) > $timeHourAgo) {
            $tweetCoinCount[$symbol]++;
        }
    }
}

print_r($tweetCoinCount);
Array
(
    [TRIG] => 0
    [BTC] => 15
    [ETH] => 15
)
```

Comment: thank you for helping out with that! I really appreciate it :) $coinSymbol array has around 1000 coins and I cant request the api more than 100 times an hour. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I know I shouldnt be right now I am using multiple applications because I cant find another way of doing it without getting the enterprise edition. Thats why I was only using a percentage of the $coinSymbol array and each application would do 100 requests each

Comment: Probably the best thing todo would be to split the symbols by the limit then do it in batches via a cron job and keep track of the queries by incrementing a query_count column in a database etc. 1k symbols is going to take a while anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, set up a couple of servers and twitter accounts and cluster the data back to a single point. (i never said that though) ;p

Comment: ok thank you I just wanted the top 10 tweeted symbols would there be a way to make the request only get these? I dont think this is possible but I thought I would ask. Right now I have to go through every symbol and get the count but if I could only request the top 10 some how, that would be amazing

Comment: When I call all 1000 symbols it dosnt put the count into the array for some symbols? It works sometimes but not all the time

Comment: You may need to check the status codes as well, how are you doing it now, hopefully not all at once.